# Getting the child of nodes of XML having attributes - Java

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I have an XML file having many nodes with attributes as well as child elements with same field name:

```
<doc>
    <str name="eventId">54605a22aa7d649f085242e3</str>
    <arr name="toolLogExt">
      <str>.xls.lck</str>
      <str>.xls.lck</str>
      <str>.xls.lck</str>
    </arr>
    <arr name="messageTech">
      <str>Java run-time error</str>
      <str>Java run-time error</str>
      <str>Java run-time error</str>
    </arr>
    <arr name="messageId">
      <str>546066238d194b463e365194</str>
      <str>546090b48d194b463e365196</str>
      <str>546090f78d194b463e365198</str>
    </arr>
    <arr name="eventType">
      <str>Run-time error</str>
    </arr>
    <str name="type">acme</str>
    <arr name="messageSolution">
      <str>XXXXX</str>
      <str>YYYYY</str>
      <str>ZZZZZ</str>
    </arr>
    <arr name="toolID">
      <str>54605d7d8d194b463e36517e</str>
      <str>54605d7d8d194b463e36517e</str>
      <str>54605d7d8d194b463e36517e</str>
    </arr>
</doc>
```

I have read many posts on Stack-Overflow but I haven't come up across an XML Format like this. One of the regular ways is to do individual string processing after getting every node with their respective attributes and maintain a count to construct a Document Model later. However, is there a direct method to obtain all the fields?

**Edit1**
My approach so far....

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;
public class ParseSAX extends DefaultHandler {
    List<String> errorsLister;
    String inpXMLFileName;
    public ParseSAX(String xmlFileName) {
        this.inpXMLFileName = xmlFileName;
        errorsLister = new ArrayList<String>();
        parseDocument();
    }
    private void parseDocument() {
        // parse
        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
            parser.parse(inpXMLFileName, this);
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            System.out.println("ParserConfig error");
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            System.out.println("SAXException : xml not well formed");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IO error");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String s, String s1, String elementName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

        if (elementName.equalsIgnoreCase("str")) {
            String temp = (attributes.getValue("eventId"));
            // This would give me the event ID
            // Further usage
        }
        // if current element is publisher
        if (elementName.equalsIgnoreCase("arr")) {
           String temp = attributes.getValue("messageTech");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void endElement(String s, String s1, String element) throws SAXException {
        // Can't seem to figure out what to do here!!!
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ParseSAX("..//input2.xml");

        // To individually get field values having attribute names
        // I know we can do this .... 
        /**
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document dDoc;
            dDoc = builder.parse("..//input2.xml");
            XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
            String string = (String) xPath.evaluate("/response/result[@name='response']/doc/arr[@name='messageId']/str", dDoc, XPathConstants.STRING);
        } catch (SAXException | IOException | XPathExpressionException | ParserConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        **/
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "field name"? What have you tried so far? It's unclear what the issue is - it's reasonably easy to fetch attribute values, and it's reasonably easy to fetch the text value of an element...

Comment: Let's say I fetch a node having <arr> and attribute having [@name='toolLogExt']. How can I get all the child nodes belonging to this node as they all are having field <arr> ? I am posting my code snippets upto now in an edit..

Comment: It's easy to fetch individual values and even the text value of an element....But how do we fetch all the child fields? belonging to this matching node?...and all the children having the same field name -- like <str> above

Comment: You can search for `name` attribute in the XML file. Once u get that node cast it `Element` type & then fetch all elements inside that element by using `element.getElementsByTagName(subTagName)`.

Comment: Have a look at my answer. I hope it helps you.

Comment: Is there any reason you're using a SAX parser? That's making your life *much* harder than it needs to be. Unless your document is huge, I'd strongly recommend loading it into a DOM representation.

Comment: Yes, I found out now about various XML Representations. I will study about the DOM parsing. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read elements inside any XML tag using below function.

```
public class XmlFileReader{
    public NodeList readXML(String filePath, String tagName, String subTagName, String tagAttr) {
        try {
            // Get XML file object.
            File fXmlFile = new File(filePath);

            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

            NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName(tagName);

            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                Node node = nodeList.item(i);
                if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element element = (Element) node;
                    if (element.getAttribute("name").equalsIgnoreCase(tagAttr)) {
                        NodeList elementsByTagName = element.getElementsByTagName(subTagName);
                        return elementsByTagName ;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            StringWriter stack = new StringWriter();
            e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(stack));
            LogManager.fatal(stack.toString(), ReadTemplate.class.getName());
        }
        return elementsByTagName;
    }
}
```

**Function Call :**

```
XmlFileReader xmlFileReader = new XmlFileReader();
NodeList toolLogExtChilds = xmlFileReader.readXML("Path to XML file",
                "arr", "str", "toolLogExt");
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I am trying out your solution.

Comment: Do u get solution with above answer ?

Comment: Too late coming after 7 years .. but yes, I did 

Comment: @G.One, Good to know you got the answer you were looking for :)